# Solving a Diophantine equation3

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations, integers

The Diophantine equation that I have to solve is:
$$343x^2-27y^2=1$$
This question has already been posted by other user but it has not received an answer.
I proved to solve it.

This is my attempt:

substituting for $x^2=u$ and $y^2=v$ the equation becomes a Diophantine linear equation:$$343u-27v=1$$
using Euclid's algorithm to solve the equation, the solutions are:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
u=10+27k \\
v=127+343k\end{array} 
\right.
$$
substituting these solutions in first equation we obtain:
$$y^2=127+343\cdot (\frac {x^2-10}{27})$$
$x^2-10$ has to be a multiple of $27$ therefore $$x^2=c27+10 \tag{1}$$ (with $c$ integer)

$(1)$ becomes $$(x-1)(x+1)=9\cdot (3c+1)$$
obtaining two systems:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
x+1=n9 \\
x-1=\frac {3c+1}{n}\end{array} 
\right.
$$
and 
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
x-1=n9 \\
x+1=\frac {3c+1}{n}\end{array} 
\right.
$$
The solution of the first is $c=3p+1$ (with $p$ integer):
indeed if $x+1\equiv 0\pmod 3$ $c$ has to be $c\equiv 1\pmod 3$ because $c(x-1)-1$ has to be a multiple of $3$.
The solution of the second system is $c=3p+2$: indeed if $x-1\equiv 0\pmod 3$ $c\equiv 2\pmod 3$. How can I can continue and are there other solutions?

Comment: Please link to the prior question.

Comment: The question has been closed

Comment: But you can still link to it. Maybe it will get reopened.

Comment: @BillDubuque http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1282128/227073

Comment: 376766, 1342879 ?

Comment: http://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM
check step by step solution

Comment: @yimin I tried this but I cannot run it with my new java-version. Do you know what I must do that it runs ?

Comment: @Peter i am no expert of this, I used firefox under Ubuntu 14.04 to open it, I just filled the numbers and click on solve it.

Comment: @Peter http://www.emis.de/journals/AMUC/_vol-71/_no_2/_mollin/mollin.pdf is the method from.

Comment: Whenever the Pell equation has a solution.  It has infinitely many solutions.  This is true for both equations.    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128930/whenever-pells-equation-proof-is-solvable-it-has-infinitely-many-solutions/831363#831363  The same is true for the equation which led.

Answer (score 0):

For generalization of the Pell equation question arises constantly. For example in this thread.

[Whenever Pell's equation proof is solvable, it has infinitely many solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128930/whenever-pells-equation-proof-is-solvable-it-has-infinitely-many-solutions/831363#831363)

So writes the Pell equation in General form.

$$Ap^2-Bs^2=1$$

If we know any solution of this equation. $( p ; s)$

If we use any solutions of the following equation Pell.

$$x^2-ABy^2=1$$

Then the following solution of the desired equation can be found by the formula.

$$p_2=xp+Bys$$

$$s_2=xs+Ayp$$

Answer (score 0):

$343x^2-27y^2=1$

$⇒343x^2≡1 mod 27$

$343≡19 mod 27$

we can find that if $x=8$ we get:

$343 . 8^2 ≡ 1 mod 27$

We can see that x belong to a set its members make an arithmetic progression and have following specification:

$s . 19 ≡ 1 mod 27$; $s = [10, 37, 64, . . a+27k]$

where $a=10$; and $d=27$ is common ratio.

With $k=5257504398$ we get $x=376766$

Also $y^2=343 k$ that gives $y=1342879$

Therefore the parametric solution is:

$x=\sqrt{10+27k}$

$y=\sqrt{343 k}$

This equation probably has more solutions.