# Proof $x^2-dy^2=-1$ is unsolvable in integers if $\sqrt{d}$ has continued fraction expansion of even period

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions, pell-type-equations

I want to prove that the negative Pell's equation

$$x^2-dy^2=-1$$

is unsolvable in integers if $\sqrt{d} = [a_0, \overline{a_1, \dots, a_n}]$ with $n$ even and minimal (minimal since all $\sqrt{d}$ can be written like this by writing $\sqrt{d}  = [a_0, \overline{a_1, \dots, a_n,a_1, \dots, a_n}]$).

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3734887/602386) question is more general, asking for no solutions when $n$ is even, and infinitely many when $n$ is odd. [I answered the odd case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4830730/602386), but I've been struggling to come up with how to do the even case, and am unable to find a source on this.

All I seem to find is the necessary but not sufficient condition that the equation is solvable if $d$ is divisible neither by $4$ nor by a prime of the form $4k+3$ (see [here](https://oeis.org/A031396) for example) which is not what I'm looking for.

Can someone give me a pointer on how I may show that the equation has no solutions under the condition that the continued fraction expansion has even period?

Comment: See [Elementary Theory of Numbers by Wallow Sierpinski, chapter 8, theorem 9](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.zamlynska-9590d58f-2126-44bf-a4e1-045999087b61?q=bwmeta1.element.dl-catalog-556369c7-b6cc-4a5b-be36-bfc8e0ca7cfa;5&qt=CHILDREN-STATELESS)